# Hidden UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm writing an app that has a 5 item TabBar.  When launching, I want the app to show the contents of the view for the first item, without showing the Tabbar.  I want a hidden button to cover the full screen so that when I tap anywhere the TabBar pops up from the bottom.  I then want it to hide itself again after a few seconds.

I guess it isn't vital that it not show the TabBar on launch if it will hide itself after the predetermined time frame.

I'm new to programming, and I'm having difficulty making this happen.  I've looked at the suggestions for similar questions, but they don't seem to help.  Any suggestions for making this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example code "The Elements". It hides the tab bar when you select an element.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I looked at the sample code, but it only slides another view in when you make a selection from the TableView.  I'm wanting the current view selected by the TabBarItem to take over the whole view.  Ideally, I would like the TabBar to appear and dissappear in a manner similar to the keyboard.

Comment: I think you did not look at the code properly, so I am reading it for you. In the file AtomicElementViewController there is the magic line:

    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

Also look at the answer here at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview

This, in addition to using NSTimer, should give you enough ammunition to do what you want.  The next help I could possibly give you is writing the code for you, which I won't.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will look into this further.  I appreciate your patience with me.  I'm new at this and trying to make sense of it all.