# Partial Curl Modal Transition Style While Preserving Tool/Tab Bar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Is there a way to present a modal view controller that doesn't cover the tab bar of a UITabBarController?

Specifically I want to use the UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl, but preserve the bottom bar, a la the iPhone maps app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have two view controllers
2. In the first have the second as a subview
3. Add your toolbar as a subview to the first and call bringSubviewToFront:
4. Present the modal in the second

Answer (score -2):

> [UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
>   When the view controller is presented,
>   one corner of the current view curls
>   up to reveal the modal view
>   underneath. On dismissal, the curled
>   up page unfurls itself back on top of
>   the modal view. A modal view presented
>   using this transition is itself
>   prevented from presenting any
>   additional modal views.

And

> [hidesBottomBarWhenPushed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) A
>   Boolean value indicating whether the
>   bar at the bottom of the screen is
>   hidden when the view controller is
>   pushed on to a navigation controller.
>
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL
>   hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
>
> Discussion
>
> If
>   YES, the bar at the bottom of the
>   screen is hidden; otherwise, NO. If
>   YES, the bottom bar remains hidden
>   until the view controller is popped
>   from the stack.

There are [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview) around [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655309/tabbar-support-of-three20-iphone-photo-gallery) on stackoverflow in the past

Comment: This does not work. If you set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `NO` and present it modally with style `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`, it still curls the toolbar up.