# Is there an iphone photo thumbnail viewer and browser that is easy to use?

Tags: ios5, three20, thumbnails, photo-gallery

I'm adding a thumbnail photo gallery to my iPhone app which will include an iPhone Photo App-like photo browser plus a detail view for each photo.  So far the only thing I've found that provides this is [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20/) -- the thing is that Three20 is so huge and has a complex looking API which is not a standard Apple style interface as far as I can tell.

I've also seen this post [Open source photo viewer for IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163847/open-source-photo-viewer-for-iphone) which mentions a couple of other photo browsers -- but these don't have thumbnail galleries built in.

My question is: does anybody know of a good combination photo-browser and thumbnail gallery library which is easy to use, not excessively large and easy to customize?  Cacheing is also crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer to my own question called [KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser) which fits the bill exactly -- just a thumbnail gallery and photo browser.  Combined with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which handles the image cacheing it appears to be a perfect simple solution that doesn't require 2 MB of code!

Update: quick to install, works with tab bar controller (example app provided!) and works like a charm.  May not have all the features of Three20 but its a lot easier to use and has a much smaller footprint.  TabBarController woes made the final decision, I spent several hours trying to get Three20 photo viewer to play nice with my tab controller app -- and failed!  After only a half an hour of futzing I got KTPhotoBrowser working by using their [tab sample app](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser/tree/master/src/TabBarSample) as a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

I know `Three20` looks huge, but it is the best from my point of view. I also had problems to start, but I was able to make it. I have sample code here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655309/tabbar-support-of-three20-iphone-photo-gallery) and on [github](https://github.com/doonot/TTThumbsViewController-in-a-TabBar-App). Check it out, you will see that is exactly what you need.

Comment: I actually have been trying it out -- it's just a big learning curve for a hard deadline!  It looks like there is a lot of UrlRequest support but having trouble figuring out how to use it... we'll see!