# Removing the tabBar from a pushed view

Tags: iphone

How is the tabBar of a viewController that is pushed into view removed?

I have one view which has a tabBar and then this view pushes another view. The view being pushed can then return back the the first view as usual with a navigationController. My issue is that I want a toolbar instead of a tabbar in the pushed view.

If I hide this tab bar, there is just a blank space and my toolbar isnt even visible using

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Is this self.navigationController pointing to the first view which pushed the view calling this statement?

How can the second view(the pushed view) have is own toolbar accessed and displayed, with the tabbar from the first view hidden?

One example would be the photos app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview) addresses your issue. Basically there is a method `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` that will give you that space, just be sure that you have set up your view to expand to fill the space (I use the little springs and ibars in Interface Builder).

Comment: Nice 1 Walter. This is what I was after. :)