# problem in hiding tabbarController in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm displaying a list employess when clicking on tabBarButton. I want to hide the tabBar when I click on the cell to dispaly details of the employ and I want to show tabBar when I come back to the list .
 please anyone help me.
thanks in advance
laxmi

Comment: the answer you are looking for is under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview question

Answer (score 0):

```
[ViewControllerToBePushed setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```