# Removing tab bar from view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that has many different views that I control through a uitabbar. Now, I have one XIB window called mainWindow.xib and within here I have defined each section to the appropriate view controller via interface builder. I have one view called "random" where I would like to remove the uitabbar (I need more space on the screen) and then add it again once the user is no longer in this view. I have seen some methods by other individuals that refer to creating arrays and removing from there but I feel this is not appropriate for me since all the views are controlled through interface builder.

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview

Comment: Thank you railwayparade!