# How to set modal segue animation the same as push segue animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, segue

There are four kinds of animations provided by apple with the modal segue. But neither is my favorite, I prefer the animation like the push segue animation? How could I archive it? Is there any open source code for custom segue with different animations? Thanks in advance!

ps. Actually I have a tabView with several child view, one of them is a tableView, each cell will drill in an detail view. It is normal to push the detail view, but I do not want the tab bar come into the detail view as well. Then I choose modal the detail view. But i prefer the push animation.

Comment: Animations are not just about preference of the developer but the experience of the user. Pushing a modal is going to disorient and confuse your users. If you want to push a view then you should actually push the view, Modal views and views pushed on the stack are meant to serve separate purposes.

Comment: @RyanPoolos I think you are right

Comment: @RyanPoolos Actually I have a tabView with several child view, one of them is a tableView, each cell will drill in an detail view. It is normal to push the detail view, but I do not want the tab bar come into the detail view as well. Then I choose modal the detail view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After seeing your comment I figured this would help. There is a setting to hide your tabBar when pushing instead of you having to fake a push with a modal transition.

[image]

Also in code can be easier. Check out this SO [Hiding UITabBar when pushing a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview Check this question on why it isn't working :)

Comment: If the detail view is just a UIViewController, works, but if it is a UITableViewController, DON'T WORK. It's odd.

Comment: Very odd indeed. But lately I've had a knack for uncovering Apple framework oddities lol.

Comment: works now. the     self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
should not put in the - (void)viewDidLoad, I think maybe it should be put in  "- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender:"

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out :) Happy Coding.