# How to hide tabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have changed the frame of the tabBar in the viewController:

```
self.tabBar.frame.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame).
```

But tabBars reset to their Original frame when a new ViewController is pushed.
How can I hide the tabBar when I push a new ViewController?

Comment: I guess you're using Auto Layout, right? You should set the constraints instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding UITabBar when pushing a UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675887/hiding-uitabbar-when-pushing-a-uiview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` on your `UIViewController`.

Comment: Right, this can be achieved. But when I return, I need to show tabbar。      -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
}                                                                                                                            It's not working.